# How to connect Tableau to Databricks Spark cluster?

Tags: tableau-api, databricks

I want to do some data analytics work by leveraging Databricks spark cluster and connect my Tableau desktop to it for data visualization. Does anyone have experience and can share here? Thank you very much.

Comment: does this help? https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/tableau.html

Comment: Thanks. I already read that, it was not clear to a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated link, if you follow this closely you will be able to make the connection and send requests to the thrift server that connects you to the data coming from databricks: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/bi/tableau.html